# How to use Oracle UDT constructor as a parameter using Microsoft Oracle Provider?

Tags: arrays, oracle, parameter-passing, user-defined-types

Basically, I need to pass an array of string to a procedure.

So I have created a UDT which is defined this way at schema level:

```
TYPE SCHEMA_NAME.T_STRINGARRAY AS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Now what I want to do is to execute this statement from my C# data access:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PACKAGE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME(T_STRINGARRAY(:P0, :P1, :P2))
```

When I execute the query in Toad it is working fine but when I call the statement from C# I get this error:

```
ORA-00904: "T_STRINGARRAY": invalid identifier
```

Any help would by greatly appreciated.